# BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe in python3

Tags: python-3.x, broken-pipe

```
import sys 

input_1 = sys.argv[1]

in_1 = open(input_1, 'r')

input_lines = in_1.readlines()

in_1.close()

length = len(input_lines)

for line in range(3,length):

    print(line,input_lines[line], end="")

exit()
```

I am getting BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32].

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue with the code you posted. Something else is going on here. Are you piping to some other program that is closing the pipe?

e.g. `script.py input.txt | head` or `script.py input.txt | tail`

If so then just store the output in a file or variable first. For example:

```
script.py input.txt > output.txt
head output.txt
```

Or...

```
output=$(script.py input.txt)
head <<<"$output"
```

If you just want to suppress the error, you can replace the end of your script with the following:

```
try:
    for line in range(3, length):
        print(line, input_lines[line], end="")
except BrokenPipeError:
    pass
```